# Can Not get Filepath from URI, No such File or Directory Found exception

Tags: java, android, ftp, filepath, filenotfoundexception

I've tried to get File path of a file from Android Device and store it on FTP server using Intent,FILE object is initialized from the path I get from URI Template but when i send this File object to FileInputStream it gives me exception of File Not Found

```
 Uri uri;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    if (requestCode==6 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        uri=data.getData();//return URI of selected File
        File fil= null;
        try {
            fil = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
            fis= new FileInputStream(fil);
            client.storeFile(filePath,fis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
 private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = NavigationDrawer.this.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = 0;//cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What does `uri` and the output of `getRealPathFromURI` look like? There's a real possibility you wont be able to get an absolute file path at all (you may find this [blog post by commonsware useful](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html))

Comment: This is Value of Uri "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A13425"
and this is the output of getRealPathFromURI "image:13425"

Answer (score 0):

You probably wont be able to get access to the absolute file path from your Uri. Instead, if you require a file path, you can try to open an `InputStream` on that Uri, and use it copy the file to a location that is accessible to your app. For example:

```
try (InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)) {
    final File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename");
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.read(buffer))>0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
    }
    //File copy's finished, so you can access its path
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        client.storeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),fis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this  to  get absolute path from Device, It works fine when i select file from SD Card but didnt work on Internal storage
    String fullpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+filePath;